# Show videos in tag <video> with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

View:

```
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="x in content.spells">
....
    <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(content.id) | trusted )}}"   controls>
          Seu navegador não suporta o elemento <code>video</code>.
    </video>
....
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getIdVideo = function(videoId){
    videoId = videoId.toString();
    for (var i=0; i<=4; i++){
      if (videoId.length != 4){
        //videoId = videoId.push('0');
        videoId = "0"+videoId;
      }

    }

    return 'http://cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/'+videoId+'_02.mp4';
  };
```

The same video is shown 4 times.
[image: The same video is shown 4 times]

I call this function `getIdVideo()` that returns a video according with the `id`. The way i do shows tha same video 4 times. The problem is that i need to show 4 videos to each `id` just changing, from 02 to 05, the number after "_" in url:

> http:/cdn.leagueoflegends.com/champion-abilities/videos/mp4/'+videoId+'_02.mp4

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, `id` seems to be on content. But you need to set `id` on `content.spells`.

Then you can use

```
    <video width="320" height="240" ng-src="{{(getIdVideo(x.id) | trusted )}}"   controls>
```